# How to return a boolean value from a function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have `column a` and `column b` in table `emp`. I'd like to retrieve values from those columns and find the difference between them with a function. The function would return *true* for a 0 difference otherwise return *false*. I don't know how to return a value.

Also, how do I store the retrieved values in a variable?

Answer (score 23):

MySQL doesn't really have booleans. `TRUE` and `FALSE` are aliases to 1 and 0, and the `BOOL` column type is just an alias for `TINYINT(1)`. All expressions that appear to give boolean results actually return 0 or 1.

You could write your query as:

```
SELECT (a = b) AS a_equals_b
FROM emp
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 14):

```
select a, b, if(a-b=0, true, false) as diff from emp;
```

Comment: +1 for giving a way to phrase the result, didn't know that "if" instruction for MySQL

Answer (score -4):

go to

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html

section

BOOL, BOOLEAN